# Is the method call along with the book-keeping to send funds to a smart contract and the transaction to actually transfer funds separate?

Tags: transactions, payable

I am new to ethereum or any blockchain for that matter. I have conceptual questions after looking at the "Fundme" example from freecodecamp.

The simplified fund() method does simple book-keeping - keeps a map of addresses that have sent it funds along with the value of the funds as shown below:

```
function fund() public payable {
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }
```

A few questions:

1. Is the data in addressToAmountFunded and funders, memorialized in a transaction on the block?
2. I assume yes, and if yes, is the transaction to actually credit the smart contract address and debit the sender's address a separate ethereum transaction?
3. Is there some magic happening with the payable modifier behind the scenes?
4. If separate, it would appear that they could be memorialized in separate blocks. Is that possible and what would happen if one of them occurs and the other is rejected?
5. If a million funders fund the smart contract, the size of even the simple data structures addressToAmountFunded and funders can become multi-megabyte. Is it possible to store these in a single block and if not then what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to stackexchange :) (by the way, you can format your code in a block by surrounding it with 3 backtics (```) before and after, i did it for you.

1. No. This data is in your smart contracts storage. The data that gets written in a block is only the function call itself. It roughly "translates" to "hey, i'm user [address] and i want to call the function `fund()` on the smart contract at address [contractAddress] and send [value] ether alongside this call". Contract storage is managed separately from block themselves. If you want more info, read the ethereum white and yellow papers (https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/ https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)
2. No. A transaction contains multiple fields, among them are `value`, which is the amount of ETH the transaction is sending, and `data`, which in your case is the actual function call.
3. Magic? No. But something happens when you declare a function non-payable, the compiler adds behind the scenes something that would translate in solidity to

```
if(msg.value != 0) {
revert();
}
```

4. and 5. Are irrelevant, as your assumptions are wrong. But indeed, if a million user funded the smart contract, your `addressToAmountFunded` mapping would become bigger and bigger, which could cause an issue if you have, for example, a function that needs to read multiple values in it (because this function would get more and more expensive as the size of the mapping increases). About contract storage in itself, it's unlimited, you're perfectly allowed to store terabytes of data in a smart contract (if you're willing to pay the price for it)

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains. I am going to read those papers. It just seemed like a lot of effort to memorialize all the state data of a contract in the blockchain. Btw, where can i read how storage data is managed. I read the solidity docs about “storage” versus “memory” but I could not find a reference to where is this storage managed? Are specific nodes or all nodes or just the miners expected to make storage for contract data available? How is the decentralization of storage data managed?